# Convert .xlsx file into cedilla (Ç) delimited format

Tags: excel, type-conversion, file-format, saving-data

Can you please help me convert a conventional Excel document into an cedilla (Ç) delimited (upper case Ç) format like a .CSV format? To my knowledge it would be saved as a .txt file but with the upper case Ç separating each column of data. An example below of what I'm looking for:

```
AccountNameÇDateÇAccountStatusÇDateOpenedÇ
```

Comment: What software tools are you using. Is this a programming question?

Comment: Do you want an answer in VBA?

Comment: @JAL I would be open to using an VBA script if it will work. Thanks.

Comment: @JimJohnson if this is not a programming question, then StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: @JAL Based off my research this process can only be done using a programming function.

Comment: @JAL Do you have a VBA method? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Yes, all of you were correct. It was not a programming question. Here's the steps.

1. Open .xlsx file
2. Add an empty column after each column of data and input Ç for each column.
3. Concatinate all the columns
4. Save as .txt file